# How to have Label text with graphics over image(product image of e commerce app) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am trying to get a ***text label with graphics*** over the image. Labels like **new arrival, best seller, limited, on sale** just like on the pic attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTW4C.png)

Comment: For this, you can use `stack` widget.

Comment: isn't there any package to get this ,like we have for badges https://pub.dev/packages/badges ?

Comment: This design can be achieved in a simple way without using packages. If you are not familiar with the `stack` widgets, you can watch tutorials about `stack` widgets on youtube and so on.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71642790/7527342) shows detail on how you can achieve the design.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i think the skeletal layout would be :

```
return Stack(
  children: [
    Card(
      color: Colors.black54,
      child: Image.asset('assets/xyz.png'),
    ),
    Align(
      //for bottomRight
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/fireimg.png',
      ), //can be an SVG converted to png
    ),
    Align(
      //for topLeft
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/label.png',
      ), //can be an SVG converted to png
    ),
  ],
);
```

Feel free to give the `Padding` of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

it has so much code to write , so i will give some examples to achieve that output

[image]

in this image ,i mentioned 0 and one .

**for all 1**

*solution 1*

you can use image like this way

```
            Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.amber,// added only for view this example 
                  child:Image() // add Product image here
                ),
                Positioned(
                    top: 20, //change  according to your use case position
                    left: 0,// change  according to your use case position
                    child: Container(
                    color: Colors.black, // added only for view this example 
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(image: ),// add label image here
                      width: 100,
                      height: 50,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [Text('hi')],
                      ),
                    ))
              ],
            )
```

*solution 2*

you can use `custom paint` for label layout

```
not that

in both solution you have to use stack and position widgets , you can control position according to your use case
```

**for all 0**

you can use `RotationTransition` widgets to achieve this

[image]

```
not that

you have to use stack and position widgets , you can control position according to your use case
```

**for the vertical Text**

use this example

```
String exText = "meta";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('hi'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: Column(
            children: exText.characters
                .map((e) => Container(
                      child: Text('$e'),
                    ))
                .toList()),
      ),
```

out put will be

[image]